# How to send a jpg image to the server with react-camera?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, npm

My Goal is to upload an image taken from a webcam to a Lambda function which then uploads it to AWS S3.

The lambda function seems to work when I test it, however I can't work out what exactly needs to be sent through from the React Camera.
Or if I am sending through the right format to upload it.

```
import Camera from 'react-camera';
```

..
This is the JSX

```
<Camera
  ref={(cam) => {
    this.camera = cam;
  }}
>
  <Button onClick={this.takePicture}>
    <i className="fas fa-camera"></i> &nbsp; Take photo
  </Button>
</Camera>
```

This is the react code that is called when they take the photo

```
takePicture = () => {
  this.camera.capture()
    .then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
      this.props.dispatch(uploadImage(blob))
    })
}
```

The uploadImage function in my action is:

```
export const uploadImage = (fileObj) => dispatch => {

  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'image/jpeg'
    },
    body: fileObj
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        console.log(response);
        // ... Show feedback
        return response
      } else {
        // ... Show feedback
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    });
}
```

I figure I need to upload a base64 image..?
I don't understand how I get that from the `blob`

---

Here is the Lambda Function code for reference:

```
  var params = { 
    Bucket: 'bucketName', 
    Key: Date.now() + '.jpg',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    Body: event.body,
    ACL: "public-read"
  };
  return uploading = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
        state.uploadError = err
        return reject({
          error: err,
          status: 'error',
          message: 'something went wrong'
        })
      }
      state.uploadData = data
      state.fileLocation = data.Location
      state.status = "success"
      state.message = "File has been uploaded to the fileLocation"
      return resolve(data)
    });
  })
```

**Question:**

How do I make the format of the `blob` correct so that when it's `POST`ed though as the `body` it will be the correct image format?

Comment: Would just base64 encode image to an string and send that one to an server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very well organized question and code... thank you!

Updated:
Use the filesystem module to read the file and specify the encoding.

```
const fs = require('fs');

takePicture = () => {
  this.camera.capture()
    .then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
      const image = fs.readFileSync(blob.path);
      const b64Image = Buffer.from(image).toString('base64');
      this.props.dispatch(uploadImage(b64image));
    })
}
```

Comment: I think it would help OP if you explained why they should do it the way you suggested.

Comment: Thanks @Taylor, I get this error when passing passing blob into the Buffer: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
Any ideas? :)

Comment: Updated answer! Should have better luck with this one.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, since OP is asking about a client-side component, and blobs emphatically don't have filesystem paths...

Comment: ... good point about this being a client-side component! My answer wouldn't work.  However, I thought blob was just the name he was giving the output of `camera.capture()`.